# SPOJ command line submission: What to include in POST method?

Tags: python, post

Right now I am writing a snippet allowing submitting code to http://www.spoj.com/ from command line, i.e. something like `python spoj_cl.py test.cpp`

I understand that I need to send a POST request to the corresponding URL with specified parameters and cookie, but I'm still confused on which parameters to include on. Right now I'm doing it in a trial-and-error method, which seems not to be very effective. My questions are:

1. How to check systematically which parameters to be included in when sending a POST request?
2. How can I check immediately if the POST request I send is successful? One way I could think of is to get the content of the submission page http://www.spoj.com/status/, but checking the request directly should be preferable.

Below is the snippet I'm working on. Hopefully it should be readable.

```
import requests, sys

# if __name__ == "__main__":
base_url = "http://spoj.com"
autologin_hash = "*************" # Your user hash, taken from cookie
autologin_login = "************" # Your user name
session_id = "************" # Login session, can be retrieved when logged in

cookies_info = {
    "autologin_login": autologin_login,
    "autologin_hash": autologin_hash
}

ext_id = {
    "cpp": "1"
}

filename = "test.cpp"
problem_name = str(filename.split(".")[0]).upper()
extension = filename.split(".")[1]

submit_url = base_url + "/submit/"
parts = {
    "PHPSESSID": session_id,
    "action": "/submit/complete",
    "file": open(filename, "rb"),
    "subm_file": "",
    "lang": ext_id[extension],
    "problemcode": problem_name
}

requests.post(submit_url, 
    params={"PHPSESSID": session_id},
    files=parts,
    cookies=cookies_info)
print "Submission sent!"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. How to check systematically which parameters to be included in when sending a POST request?

I am not a member of the site spoj.com, but what you are asking for is basic web scraping. Find the HTML form for submitting code on the website, then use Firebug or Chrome developer console to find the HTML input elements with name attributes. Once you have found them, you can make a Python script to check for these elements systematically. If one day the elements are missing, the page probably changed.

Example Code:

```
webpage = requests.get(form_url, params={"PHPSESSID": session_id}, cookies=cookies_info)
html = BeautifulSoup(webpage.text)
form = html.find('form')
inputs = form.findAll('input')
names = []
for i in inputs:
    names.append(i['name'])
```

2. How can I check immediately if the POST request I send is successful?

Check the status code of the response. It should be `200` for successful requests.

```
# Make the request
r = requests.post(submit_url, 
    params={"PHPSESSID": session_id},
    files=parts,
    cookies=cookies_info)

# Check the response code
if r.status_code == '200':
    print "Submission successful!"
else:
    print "Submission met a status code of: %s" % r.status_code
```

Comment: I should clarify for the second part, the problem is that, even when I send a POST request without complete arguments, I still get 200 response but there's no successful submission performed.

Comment: Ah, in that circumstance you may have to scrape the result page for UI errors.